# Save two dimensional table to database

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, sqlite

How can I represent the following table in database efficiently, assuming that the number of rows and cols is more the several hundreds (I think creating database with 100 fields is not a good idea:))

[image]

I'm using Ruby on Rails/SQLite.

Comment: Do ALL rows have hundreds of columns?  Or just hundreds of possible values, but only a few are actually populated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have here is a classical de-normalisation task. And the classical approach (not knowing your read-write patterns or other needs) is to make three tables:

```
ID | Name
---------
1  | Gothamist
2  | GigaOm
3  | Quick Online Tips

ID | Name
----------
1  | China
2  | Kids
3  | Music
4  | Yahoo

ID1 | ID2 | Value
-----------------
1   | 1   |  0
1   | 2   |  3
...
3   | 4   |  22
```

Comment: This might suggest that the OP should use a key-value store rather than a RDB.

Comment: Possibly. That was my initial point: it is really hard to come up with a design suggestion without knowing the needs in terms of read-write patterns, performance etc. Might be a NoSQL case, might be RDB, might be bespoke in-memory thing.

Answer (score 2):

Your data structure is a bipartite non-directional weighted graph. If you can use a graph database, that would be a good fit.

Answer (score 0):

100s of fields are most likely not normalized, but it's not always true.  Normalization is your objective, not a hard and fast rule about numbers of columns.

It's hard to answer this question, because the columns and keys don't make much sense to me.

I can see a one-to-many relationship here, but that's the only suggestion that's obvious.